# Using rlang's sym inside a function and getting error

Tags: r, function, rlang

I have the following function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

custom_filter <- function(
  df,
  pos_filter_1 = NULL,
  ct_filter_1,
  filter_1
){
  pos_filter_1 <- paste0("df$", pos_filter_1)
  
  position_filter_1 <- if (!is.null(pos_filter_1)) (match.fun(filter_1)(!!rlang::sym(pos_filter_1), ct_filter_1)) else TRUE

  fin_df <- df %>%
    dplyr::filter(position_filter_1)
  
  return(fin_df)
}
```

However, when I try to use it on a dataframe, I get the error `Error in !rlang::sym(pos_filter_1) : invalid argument type`. Here is an example in which I try to filter on rows in which the column `qb_count` is less than or equal to 5:

```
df <- tibble(x1 = letters[1:9],
             qb_count = 1:9,
             rb_count = 10:18)

custom_filter(df, 'qb_count', 5, "<=")
```

What am I missing? This works fine if I do it outside of the function. Appreciate any help!

Comment: The contents of `pos_filter_1` isn’t a symbol, it’s a (string that parses as a) complex expression. You could use `parse` (or `rlang::parse_expr`) here, but shouldn’t. Instead of constructing expressions from code strings, use `bquote` or `substitute` (or `rlang::(en)quo` or `rlang::(en)expr`). But as akrun’s answer shows, none if this is necessary here — just use the unqualified column name directly. Constructing a subset expression (`df$…`) is an unneeded detour.

Answer (score 1):

We may create the `if/else` as

```
custom_filter <- function(
  df,
  pos_filter_1 = NULL,
  ct_filter_1,
  filter_1
){
  
 
if(is.null(pos_filter_1)) {
 df

} else {
  df %>%
    
    dplyr::filter(match.fun(filter_1)(!! rlang::ensym(pos_filter_1),
         ct_filter_1) )
  
  
  }
  }
```

-testing

```
>   custom_filter(df, NULL, 5, "<=")
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  x1    qb_count rb_count
  <chr>    <int>    <int>
1 a            1       10
2 b            2       11
3 c            3       12
4 d            4       13
5 e            5       14
6 f            6       15
7 g            7       16
8 h            8       17
9 i            9       18
> custom_filter(df, 'qb_count', 5, "<=")
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  x1    qb_count rb_count
  <chr>    <int>    <int>
1 a            1       10
2 b            2       11
3 c            3       12
4 d            4       13
5 e            5       14
```

---

Or an easier option without having to check with `if/else` is wrapping the code in `if_any/if_all` (it should work with one or more columns) and using `any_vars` (if the column is not present, it wouldn't evaluate)

```
custom_filter <- function(
  df,
  pos_filter_1 = NULL,
  ct_filter_1,
  filter_1
  )
  {



  df %>%    
    dplyr::filter(if_any(any_of(pos_filter_1), 
          ~ match.fun(filter_1)(.x,
                ct_filter_1) ))
  
  
  
  }
```

-testing

```
>   custom_filter(df, NULL, 5, "<=")
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  x1    qb_count rb_count
  <chr>    <int>    <int>
1 a            1       10
2 b            2       11
3 c            3       12
4 d            4       13
5 e            5       14
6 f            6       15
7 g            7       16
8 h            8       17
9 i            9       18

>   custom_filter(df, 'qb_count', 5, "<=")
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  x1    qb_count rb_count
  <chr>    <int>    <int>
1 a            1       10
2 b            2       11
3 c            3       12
4 d            4       13
5 e            5       14
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the way that I had it with the `position_filter_1` logic separate and then plugging that into the `filter()`? This function will eventually have several of these filters and I still get the same error in my code even if I switch it to `rlang::ensym()`

Comment: @SamHoppen What I understand is that if the `pos_filter_1` is NULL value, then you don't need the `filter` at all i.e. return the full dataset.  Wouldn't this be a more clear logic to separate those two cases instead of doing the `filter` unnecessarily

Comment: @SamHoppen I guess the updated option should be more convenient for you instead of checking with `if/else`